# Translation of a text column in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, language-translation, google-translation-api, google-reviews

I have a table in BigQuery containing consumers' reviews, some of them are in local languages and I need to use a translation API to translate them and create a new column to the existing table incorporating the transalted reviews. I was wondering whether I can automate this task? e.g. using Google Translate API in BigQuery....

Comment: Check out this demo from Cloud Next '19 - [Viant’s Journey:The Non-Engineer Guide to BigQuery](https://youtu.be/BpgW27YLSS8?t=1461) - it shows similar use case but with use of Vision API. This is done with Magnus - part of Potens.io BigQuery Tools - it is  available on [GCP Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio) for you to try. Obviously, I highly recommend to see whole video! You can see also all documentation and product videos [here](https://potensio.zendesk.com/). Disclosure - I am part and lead of Potens.io Team (also stated in my SO Profile)

Answer (score 1):

An alter solution to achieve this if customer review has some limited review comments in response then you can create a Bigquery function to replace values.

A sample code is given over [github](https://github.com/vibwipro/BigQuery) repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an external API in BigQuery, like a Language Translation API, you can use Remote Functions (a recent [release](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/remote-functions)).

In this [GitHub](https://github.com/justdataplease/bigquery-translation) repo you can see how to wrap the Azure Translator API (the same way you can use the Google Translate API) into a SQL function and use it in your queries.

Since you have created the Translation SQL function, you can write an update statement (and run it periodically - using scheduled queries) to achieve what you want.

```
UPDATE mytable SET translated_review_text=translation_function(review_text) WHERE translated_review_text IS NULL
```